# "colour_themes.conf" file isn't entirely working as intended in the editor space

Tags: themes, codeblocks, darkmode

As it says in the title, the colour_themes.conf file when transferred over to default.conf doesn't span the entire editing space for me. The side bar where the number of lines of code are stays white, despite it being converted to dark in every other tutorial I've watched.
[image: Here's what it looks like atm]

For reference, I'm running Windows 11.

I'm well aware that Code::Blocks doesn't allow a full dark theme conversion and the area that the .conf file is able to change would've been enough for me, but that one part staying white when it's not supposed to be makes a surprisingly huge difference. It might seem like it wouldn't, but it really does as I've seen both versions firsthand(explained later)

I'm just confused as to *why* it isn't working. I've attempted to fix this multiple times and have downloaded the .conf file from multiple sources and I'm still unable to get it to work.

I thought it was an Administrator issue because it worked flawlessly on my sister's account(Administrator), and presented this problem on my account (not Administrator) on our home PC. However, I'm currently working on my laptop, where I am the sole Administrator and it's still like this.

Any suggestions on how to make it work properly would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that conf file won't change the side bar colour of CodeBlocks, at least on 20.03 it can't, maybe in the past it would. I've used the themes so far, and I didn't get the side bar dark, either. To make it dark, manually set from `Settings->Environment->Colors->Editor`, choose a proper color for line number background.

Edit: If you're delighted to have a full-dark CodeBlocks, then it's the time! Since wxWidgets 3.3 Release, CodeBlocks can be in very dark mode. See:[C::B dark mode in Windows](https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=25598.0).

Comment: it's not the sidebar itself that changes colour with the editing space, only the part of the sidebar that displays which line of code you're on and how many lines of code you've written. Its strange that it doesn't get dark on my end despite getting dark on almost every tutorial I've seen so far.
Regardless, this beta dark mode build looks very promising. Thanks, I'll try it out